# how to write common insert query in pdo prepare method in php

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to write common code for insert query in pdo prepare statement.

**index.php is:**

```
<?php
include('include/header.php');
$table_name = 'office';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
include('functions.php');
$data = array();
$data = escapemydata($_POST);
unset($data['action']);
unset($data['submit']);
unset($data['id']);
$userprofileobj->insert($table_name,$data);
}       
?>
<form method="post" action="#">
<table align="left" width="100%">
<tr>
<td><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td><input type="text" name="title" required="required" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Designation</strong></td>
<td><input type="text" name="desig" required="required" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**functions.php is:**

```
<?php

function escapemydata($data = array())
{
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
 $data[$key] = $value;
}
return $data;
}
?>
```

**My operatons.php, where insert function is:**

```
public function insert($table,$data){
    if(!empty($data) && is_array($data)){
        $columns = '';
        $values  = '';
        $i = 0;

        foreach($data as $key=>$val){
            $pre = ($i > 0)?', ':'';
            $columns .= $pre.$key;

            $values  .= ":".$val.", ";
            $i++;
        }
        foreach($data as $key => $value){
            $data2[$data[$key]] = $data[$value];

        }

        $values = rtrim($values,', ');


      $stmt = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (".$columns.") VALUES (".$values.")";
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare($stmt);
        $stmt->execute($data2);


    }else{
        $this->con->close();
        return false;
    }
}
```

But query is not inserting any data.
I think $stmt->execute($data2); is not running. Because $data2 is not in proper way. How to make correct this.

Comment: If all your code is PHP related, it would be best to just tag this with just PHP because it doesn't have anything to do with Javascript.

Comment: Thankyou for reply. Now I will keep in mind your suggestion.

Comment: Do you want to actually copy `$data` to `$data2`?

Comment: From where `$val` come from? did you mean `$value`? what is the initial content of `$data`? please share it

Comment: Actually, I am trying to write a common method of insert query in pdo prepare statement. And it needs $data = [
    'name' => $name,
    'surname' => $surname,
    'sex' => $sex,
];
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, surname, sex) VALUES (:name, :surname, :sex)";
$stmt= $dpo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($data);

Comment: Thats why I need to convert.

Comment: David Winder: I updated variable, its $value

Comment: I still don't understand why you need. Can you please show what is the currently `$data` array contain?

Comment: @cloudsoft I read the comment and your need and what you ask are not the same. Please edit and ask your REAL question (`I am trying to write a common method of insert query in pdo prepare statement`) to avoid a XY problem (see here : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Please wait I am updating my question.

Comment: Please check my code. I have updated.

Comment: First of all, your `$data2` is not define outside the `foreach` loop so when you call ` $stmt->execute($data2);` it actually not define...

Comment: Thank you for reply. I updated $data2 = []; before foreach loop. BUt it also not working

Comment: Could you please add echo of the following: `$stmt, $data, $data2` before calling ` $this->con->prepare` ?

Comment: $data is Array ( [title] => name [desig] => desc )

Comment: $data2 is Array ( [name] => [desc] => )

Comment: $stmt is INSERT INTO office (title, desig) VALUES (:name, :desc)

Comment: What do you except to be in `$data2`?

Comment: $data2 should be execute by pdo method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182334/discussion-between-david-winder-and-cloud-soft).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your `$data` array has:

```
$data =  array("title" => "mrx", "desig" => "MD" );
```

You want your `sql` query to be:

```
$columns = "title, desig";
$values = ":title, :desig";
$data2 = array(":title" => "mrx", ":desig" => "MD");
$stmt = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (".$columns.") VALUES (".$values.")";
$stmt = $this->con->prepare($stmt);
$stmt->execute($data2);
```

In order to create those those you can use:

```
$columns = '';
$values  = '';
$data2 = array();

foreach($data as $key=>$val){
    $columns .= $key . ", ";
    $values  .= ":" . $key . ", ";
    $data2[":" . $key] = $val;
}
//Remove last ', ' 
$columns = substr($columns, 0, -2);
$values  = substr($values , 0, -2);
```